# Decoupling setting of specific bits (transfer mode, stream, channel) from the generic DMA_Init() function

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, dma

So with regards to DMA drivers, what's the approach for configuring certain bits generic inside a function which could be reused for both TX and RX calls which would require different stream parameter at least (On STM32F4, USART RX is on stream5 and TX is on stream6): there are bits including `stream#`, `channel number`, `transfer modes` such that they're decoupled from the generic `DMA_Init()` let's say? 
I decoupled the peripheral/memory addresses along with transferModes from the init function which I can reuse for RX, TX but does it make sense incorporate the rest inside `dma_start()` as well? Currently, I have:

```
dma_init();    // set other bits i.e word length, fifo/direct mode, fifo threshold etc
dma_start(sourceAddress, destinationAddress, transferMode);
```

The examples I've seen online do define `transferModes` and `stream` inside the `init()` function and I'm not clear on this.

So maybe I'm looking for something like:

```
dma_init();
dma_start(stream5, sourceAddress, destinationAddress, p2m); // rx from peripheral to memory

// process the data now stored in destination buffer, and send out a response
dma_start(stream6, sourceAddress, destinationAddress, m2p); // tx from mem to per
```

Answer (score 0):

An init() function should contain everything that you need to tell the driver before it starts operation. As for making a portable, abstract API for DMA, it's quite unlikely that you'll manage to create a meaningful one, since it is so very MCU-specific.

That being said, you can solve this in classic C along the lines of this:

```
// dma.h
dma_err_t dma_init (const void* settings);
```

Then implement this in a STM32-specific module:

```
// stm32_dma.h

#include "dma.h"

typedef struct
{
  /* stuff */
} stm32_dma_settings_t;
```

And then implement it accordingly:

```
// stm32_dma.c

#include "stm32_dmh.h"

dma_err_t dma_init (const void* settings)
{
  const stm32_dma_settings_t* stm32_settings = settings;
  ...
}
```

This allows you to leave out hardware-specific details from the API. The `dma_start` function can be written in the same manner, so that it takes a specific struct as parameter.

Comment: That's fine, but my question was more about making `init` function "different" from ones I can call for Tx/Rx considering how, say, uart's rx and tx connections are made on separate DMA streams, and currently I provide the stream type to `init()`.

What I'm thinking of doing is call `dma_init()` once, and then have respective calls for tx/rx as I need in the application.